# Getting code coverage in .net core, xUnit project

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, code-coverage, xunit.net

I'm trying to get code coverage in .net core project using directions from https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md#working-with-code-coverage

Test are working correctly
[image: Tests without code coverage]

However, when I add code coverage option I get this error:

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was 
forcibly closed by the remote host.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image: Tests with code coverage]

Maybe someone have experienced it and could share knowledge how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried to run powershell as an administrator this problem disappeared, so I guess it has something to do with access permissions.