# Find class or methods without unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, moq

In our project we have written unit test's for some methods, we are planning to write unit test's for methods which doesn't have 
test's.

Is there a command or tool in `Visual Studio` to automatically find class or methods without unit test's ?

Comment: what test framework are you using? mstest? xunit? perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415562/mstest-code-coverage ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46173051/getting-code-coverage-in-net-core-xunit-project ?

Comment: I see you are not new here, but is it me or this question is not belong to SO?

Comment: @MarcGravell , Thanks for the link, we are  using `MsTest`.

Comment: @SeM ,  may i know which site this question belong ?

Comment: @MarcGravell can you please clarify why you believe links you've found are not duplicates? (I think their are good dups, but clearly you thought otherwise)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov because without an answer to the question I asked, I *couldn't know* which - if either - was a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017, you can use Intellitest feature for .Net Framework projects. Intellitest didn’t support for .NET Core projects, you can try with Code Coverage feature.

Comment: Will this feature automatically find class or methods without unit test's , if so can you explain the steps to find ?

Comment: Here for Intellitest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/generate-unit-tests-for-your-code-with-intellitest and code coverage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. Code coverage  feature is only for VS Enterprise.